# The hardware of the computer which you have installed rgbdslam v2 successfully

Tags: slam, navigation, rgbdslamv2, rgbd-slam, rgbdslam-v2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Some days ago, I installed rgbdslam v2 on my computer, but when I catkin_make it I failed. I have searched the error on the Internet, somebody tell me the cpu cause that. So I want to know that someone who have installed rgbdslam v2 successfully. could you tell me the hardware of the computer  which you have installed rgbdslam v2 successfully? Thanks very much!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/201171/the-hardware-of-the-computer-which-you-have-installed-rgbdslam-v2-successfully./) by [NKUBRUCE](https://answers.ros.org/users/20833/nkubruce/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2015-01-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Original author here. I'm using an Intel i7 CPU, 16GB RAM, NVIDIA GeForce GTX 570. Below is my /proc/cpuinfo (for one core).

It also builds and runs on my Thinkpad X220 (also an Intel i7) with 8GB and Intel graphics card.

```
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 42
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2600 CPU @ 3.40GHz
stepping    : 7
microcode   : 0x14
cpu MHz     : 1600.000
cache size  : 8192 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 8
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 4
apicid      : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx lahf_lm ida arat epb xsaveopt pln pts dtherm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid
bogomips    : 6822.89
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
```

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2015-01-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [NKUBRUCE](https://answers.ros.org/users/20833/nkubruce/) on 2015-01-19**:
Thank you so much for your help! If I installed rgbdslam v2 on a thinkpad x220, can I use SIFTGPU? I have read your paper and I found that It is much better that other algorithms.

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2015-01-21**:
On mine, no. I am not sure whether there are x220 models with "real" GPU. However, I'll soon publish an update on github, where ORB is as fast and as good as SIFTGPU.

**Comment by [NKUBRUCE](https://answers.ros.org/users/20833/nkubruce/) on 2015-01-21**:
Thank you for your kindness！